# How to set an element on web page so that it doesnt affected on zoom in & out

Tags: css, asp.net

I have one wrapper class in css and another div which have on that wrapper class div.I want first div to be fixed because when zoom in the page it change its position.So how do I fix this bug....

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: scroll;
  left: 0.5%;
  right: 0.5%;
  margin-bottom: 18%;
  margin-top: 18%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-left:rgba(187,187,187,0.8) 0px solid;
  border-right: rgba(187,187,187,0.8) 0px solid;
  z-index:500;
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapper">
  <div style="float : right; margin-top: -575px; margin-right: 350px;">
    <a id="Show" href="#">
      <img src="Images/show_btn_new.gif" />
    </a>
    <a id="Hide" href="#">
      <img src="Images/hide_btn_new.gif" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the indside div of wrapper to be fixed so that zoom in & out doesnt affected it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the position property to

```
position: absolute;
```